# Getting more output of Meka API as in the GUI

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, weka

Can someone help me out here please? I am using Meka, a multi-label extension of Weka. I wish to apply multi-label classification on a dataset by using some java code I have written. However, in contrast to the GUI I don't get the amount of output. Also there is little to no (decent) documentation on how to achieve the same output as in the GUI. Here is my code so far:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Music-train.arff"));
    Instances training = new Instances(reader);

    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Music-test.arff"));
    Instances testing = new Instances(reader);

    Explorer.prepareData(training);
    Explorer.prepareData(testing);

    SMO smo = new SMO();
    MultilabelClassifier BR = new BR();
    BR.setClassifier(smo);
    BR.setOptions(Utils.splitOptions("-threshold PCutL -verbosity 4"));

    BR.buildClassifier(training);

    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(training);
    eval.evaluateModel(BR, testing);
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("Results\n======\n", true));
```

I have tried several things but do not work. Can anyone explain how I can get more output similar to the one in the GUI? I tried to raise the verbosity but nothing works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of [MEKA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meka/files/) (currently, its 1.6.2), you would find a static method in the Evaluation class as Evaluation.evaluateModel(h, D_train, D_test, top, vop); Here, provide the verbosity value as vop string, and top refers to the PCut1 or PCutL.

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 can you please verify the answer?